# Error with Firefox 21, Firebug and LessCSS

Tags: firefox, firebug, less

I have a problem since i updated to Firefox 21 my Firebug is crashing because of LessCSS when i try to debug something.

This is the message that appears when i load the site with the FireBug oppened.

```
Skript: http://local/js/devlibs/less-1.1.6.js:1209
```

And in the line 1209:

```
})(require('../tree'));
```

Any idea? It's a general problem or it's just me?

Thanks

Comment: I would upgrade Less to start off with - I think the last version I saw was 1.3.3. That will at least get you on the latest version, and that might solve the problem on its own.

Comment: LESS 1.4.0 has just been released ;) It's a tag on their github repo now

Comment: Thanks! Finally i solved the problem updating Firefox to the "Nightly" version and it worked well. 

I just was wondering if someone had the same problem or there is any kind of inconsistence between this version of Firefox and FireBug, because until firefox 20 worked well.